# Sql statement error : INNER JOIN & unknown column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I cant figur out, why this statement does not run...

```
SELECT T1.* , T2.* , T3 . * , T4 . * , T5.Sessionname, T5.Session_ID, T5.Lernsession, T5.Session_Beschreibung, T5.User_ID, T6.Username, T6.ID, T7.*
FROM Session_Fragen T1, Sessions T5


INNER JOIN Fragen T4 ON T1.Frage_ID = T4.Frage_ID
INNER JOIN Semester T2 ON T2.Semester_ID = T4.Semester_ID
INNER JOIN Faecher T3 ON T3.Fach_ID = T4.Fach_ID
INNER JOIN Userdaten T6 ON T5.User_ID = T6.ID
LEFT JOIN Medien T7 ON  T7.Frage_ID = T1.Frage_ID

WHERE 
T1.Session_ID =1655
AND T1.User_ID =2
AND T5.Session_ID =1655
AND T4.Meldung =0
AND T4.Freigabe =1
AND T5.User_ID =2

ORDER BY T4.Fach_ID
```

i'm trying to solve the error: #1054 - Unknown column 'T1.Frage_ID' in 'on clause'
for couples of hours without any success...

may anybody sees what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well, it founds like Session_Fragen does not have a Frage_ID column. What columns does that table have?

Comment: execute the following mysql statement and post the result please: show create table Session_Fragen;

Comment: CREATE TABLE `Session_Fragen` (
 `Sessionfrage_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `User_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `SF_Timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `Session_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Frage_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Userantwort1` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `Userantwort2` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `Userantwort3` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `Userantwort4` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `Userantwort5` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`Sessionfrage_ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=80055 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: Probably it should be INNER JOIN Fragen T4 ON T1.Sessionfrage_ID = T4.Frage_ID

Comment: My suggestion: Go with all ANSI style JOINs for uniformity and troubleshooting -> Replace `FROM Session_Fragen T1, Sessions T5` with `FROM Session_Fragen T1 INNER JOIN Sessions T5 ON T1.Session_ID = T5.Session_ID` _(then remove  one of the where options with T1.Session_ID or T5.Session_ID`

Comment: @ makriria: Sessionfrage_ID is the autoincrement ID. it has to be Frage_ID

Comment: You are mixing the old style JOIN with the new one,join the Sessions table explicitly

Comment: Sorry I did not see it at first glance.

Comment: SOLVED. AgRizzo's solution was right! i will post the right code in the next comment

Comment: SELECT T1.* , T2.* , T3 . * , T4 . * , T5.Sessionname, T5.Session_ID, T5.Lernsession, T5.Session_Beschreibung, T5.User_ID, T6.Username, T6.ID, T7.*
FROM Session_Fragen T1
INNER JOIN Sessions T5 ON T5.Session_ID = T1.Session_ID
INNER JOIN Fragen T4 ON T1.Frage_ID = T4.Frage_ID
INNER JOIN Semester T2 ON T2.Semester_ID = T4.Semester_ID
INNER JOIN Faecher T3 ON T3.Fach_ID = T4.Fach_ID
INNER JOIN Userdaten T6 ON T5.User_ID = T6.ID
LEFT JOIN Medien T7 ON  T7.Frage_ID = T1.Frage_ID
WHERE 
T1.Session_ID =1655
AND T1.User_ID =2
AND T4.Meldung =0
AND T4.Freigabe =1
AND T5.User_ID =2
ORDER BY T4.Fach_ID